# woocommerce_single_product_summary replace

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried to replace the content of single product page summary without success. All I could achieve so far is adding to the content using a filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 20 );
    function my_custom_action()
    {
        echo '<p>This is my custom action function</p>';
    }
```

What function can I use to replace the content rather then adding to it?

Thanks,
ukw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** is not a filter hook, **but an action hook**.

To get this working you could try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_summary_action', 1 );
function single_product_summary_action() {
    // remove the single_excerpt
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    // Add our custom function replacement
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_excerpt_custom_replacement', 20 );
}

function single_excerpt_custom_replacement() {
    echo '<p>Adding some custom content</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Still doesn't replace what it is now, only adds.

Comment: @ukw So you have certainly in your theme some related customizations made by the authors… That's why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Most likely theme author made some mods as well, I'm gonna investigate to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

add below function in child theme function.php file

// define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>This is my custom action function</p>';
}    
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly like the one I pasted in my example, it does not replace the summary content, only adds to existing content.

Comment: Same thing, doesn't replace it.

Comment: now try updated answer. first add function remove_action();